# implement tab-specific flash and redirect in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, browser

We have a Rails 5 application, and users are using multiple tabs.  The Rails implementation of redirect and flash appears to be cookies / session based.  We're running into an issue where if a user has two tabs open and in tab 1, they hit a form submit, and hit a controller that has

```
redirect_to path_a
```

and the other tab hits

```
redirect_to path_b
```

Sometimes tab number 2 redirects to path_a.  Same for flash.  Is there a mechanism in Rails (a config) or a gem that implements tab-specific redirect and flash?

Thanks for any help,
Kevin

Comment: Rails has no knowledge of browser tabs

Comment: I know, but is there a way to have a request-specific flash and redirect so that if two are coming in on the same session they don't get to the wrong tab?